# Celda como argumento en Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, formulas, parámetros

Una pregunta, se puede pasar una celda como parámetro?, veo que al pasar una celda pasa el valor pero yo quiero ver el color del fondo de la celda no solo el valor y no sirve hacerlo con la celda activa. En síntesis quisiera pasar la celda como objeto celda y no su contenido.
La idea es sumar un conjunto de celdas si el fondo es rojo y podría pasar una sola celda o un array de celdas a esa función , por ejemplo la función se llama `Sisepago` y en la formula seria `=Sisepago(A2) +Sisepago(B2)` o `=Sisepago(A2,B2)`

Answer (score 0):

Usa `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();` para tomar la celda actual, por ejemplo en `Sisepago()`

Para tomar una celda por medio de una referencia, en lugar de usar `A2` usa `"A2"`, luego getRange(referencia), luego `getBackground()` para tomar el color de la celda y luego has la comparación y operación aritmética pertinentes.

Si realmente requieres usar `A2` deberás usar `getFormula()` y luego alguna forma de parsear la referencia, por ejemplo

```
var formula = activeRange.getFormula();
var rangeA1Notation = formula.match(/\,(.*)\)/).pop();
```

Referencia

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getactiverange
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getbackground